# How to find elements in nested divs with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to find apps on the Google Play store and having trouble locating elements that are nested inside other elements. I've seen some examples in Java and not sure I'm implementing the Ruby correctly. I want to select an outer div container, then select divs within that, until I get to the app title, and print it.

I've read the documentation for Selenium WebDriver and tried to read some of the rubygem documentation, and also done Google searches for finding nested div elements with WebDriver. This is my first Selenium WebDriver project.

```
i = 0

app_cards = driver.find_elements(:class_name, "card-content")
app_details = app_cards.find_elements(:class_name, "details")
app_titles = app_details.find_elements(:class_name, "title")

app_titles.each do |app_title|
    puts "App #{i}: " + app_title.attribute("title")
    i = i + 1
end
```

I expected the script to print all the app results on a page of the Google Play store, and I get

```
main.rb:17:in `<main>': undefined method `find_elements' for #<Array:0x00005594417b5f68> (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do something like this to print all the titles

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
driver=Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 20
driver.navigate.to('https://play.google.com/store/apps')
driver.find_elements(css: '.details > .title').to_enum.with_index(1) do |element,index|
  puts "App #{index}: " +element.attribute('title')
end
```

Comment: Thanks Rajagopalan! This did exactly that. I'm wondering, how come find_elements in the selenium documentation and in the rest of my code (which seems to be working ok) uses keys like ":class", where your code uses "css:" with the ":" after "css"?

Also, will this work in the general case for any class? So, using "css:" I can put ".[classname]" and for each nested element a ">"?

Comment: Hi, `a: b` is a hash in ruby! find_element takes the hash input in my code and this`>` denotes child element in css.